# IE7 jquery selector returns "Failed"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, internet-explorer-7

I've encountered a peculiar bug in IE7, all other browsers seem to execute this code just fine.

What i'm trying to do is select the very first input/textarea on my page using this:

```
$('textarea.classname, input.classname[type=text]').first().focus();
```

This line returns the text "Failed".
In IE7 my entire application fails after executing this line and I don't quite understand why.

When I execute either one of the following lines it returns an empty jquery object which is what I'm expecting on the page I'm currently working on:

```
$('textarea.classname').first().focus();
$('input.classname[type=text]').first().focus();
```

Comment: version of jQuery? newer version doesn't support ie7,8

Comment: Does it *return* "Failed" or does it log "Failed" as an error?

Comment: Do you really need to still support IE7???

Comment: http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/when-jquery-returns-failed-in-ie-and-how-its-probably-resolved/

Comment: I'm using jquery version v1.10.2
it logs "Failed" as an error.
Granted I'd love to ditch IE7 and even 8 but if this is the only thing blocking my support for the browser, I find it worth looking into.
I can work around the problem by checking for the elements separately and checking the length of the jquery object, but still.

Comment: I'm unable to replicate your issue using IE7 emulated. Your workaround checking for length would be what i'd try too: `if($('textarea.classname, input.classname[type=text]').length) {...}`. You could even try maybe: `$('textarea.classname, input.classname[type=text]').get(0).focus();`

Comment: @Andreas thank you for the article, however nowhere in my application I us ".live()".

It might be worth noting that I'm using raphaeljs to generate about a 100 areas on this page.

Comment: BTW, are you able to replicate issue on jsFiddle? Are you testing it on IE7 or emulated mode?

Comment: I'm changing my browsermode to IE7.
jsFiddle won't work unfortunately because their site isn't optimized for IE7
your tip with ".get(0)" also crashes the application and the length check like this: $('textarea.classname, input.classname[type=text]').length too so I have to check the length using this: if($('textarea.classname').length > 0 || $('input.classname[type=text]').length > 0){

Comment: For using jsFiddle on IE7 mode, you can go there: http://jsfiddle.net/7qj4u8dy/show/   Does this page throws "Failed" msg? For me, not (OS win7)

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, but it returns the jquery object just fine

Comment: So your issue is coming from somewhere else i guess :( The last thing i'd try would be to not use comma in selector and use type selector before class one, e.g: `$('textarea.classname').add('input[type=text].classname').first().focus();`. That's said, if your issue could be checked online, it would be useful to fix your issue

Comment: @A.Wolff Amazing, it seems so stupid now but putting the type selector after the input rather than after the classname fixes the problem.

this works just fine: `$('textarea.classname, input[type=text].classname').first().focus();`
Post it as an answer so I can get you the reputation you deserve :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this fixes your issue, setting attribute selector before class one:

```
$('textarea.classname, input[type=text].classname').first().focus();
```

I cannot find any relevant link regarding this behaviour, only that DOCTYPE must be specified for IE7 to handle attribute selector, which seems unrelevant to your issue.